# MYSQL - add column and calculate days overdue for a date and sort by longest delay

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Suppose i have a `tb_invoice` table with the following fields and amounts:

```
id | transaction_id | value    | due
1  | 1              | 1109.97  | 2020-02-19
2  | 1              | 10,      | 2019-05-01
```

I want to add the value column, calculate the days of delay and sort by the longest delay.

With the query below, I can even get some kind of result, but it's still not what I need:

```
SELECT *, SUM(value) AS total, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due) as delay
FROM tb_invoice
WHERE transaction_id = 1
GROUP BY transaction_id
```

This brings me the following result:

```
id | transaction_id | value   | due | total   | delay
1  | 1              | 1109.97 | 2020-02-19    | 1119.97 | 91
```

I need to order by the longest delay and even adding order by, I couldn't! Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stumbled across [MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Your SELECT mentions a value `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due)` that is not an aggregate function and is not mentioned in your GROUP BY clause. So it actually means `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), ANY_VALUE(due))`;

A good way to think of `ANY_VALUE()` is `MAYBE_THE_VALUE_YOU_WANT_MAYBE_NOT()`. In other words, it's not deterministic.

Try this for the column value `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MIN(due))`. Use `ORDER BY MIN(due)` to get the oldest item first.